# Не выводит данные из базы при помощи NHibernate (.NET)

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Создаю модель `Customer.cs`, XML-файл `Customer.nbm.xml`, в SQL Managment Studio создаю базу данных `NHibernateDemo`, в ней таблицу `Customer`. Подключаю бд к проекту через Server Explorer. 
Далее пишу такой код в программе

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Dialect;
using NHibernate.Driver;

namespace NHibernateDemo
{

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
            {
                x.ConnectionString = "Server=OLDBLACK; Database=NHibernateDemo; Integrated Security = SSPI;";
                x.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
                x.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
            });
        cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var customers = session.CreateCriteria<Customer>()
                                   .List<Customer>();
            foreach (var customer in customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", customer.FirstName, customer.LastName);
            }
            tx.Commit();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
}
```

но при запуске на дебаг ничего не выводится, кроме надписи "Enter any key to exit..."
Как я понимаю, что-то не так со строкой соединения? как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Для файла Customer.nbm.xml надо в свойствах поставить embedded resource.